# Getting shader byte code to pass into CreateVertexShader()

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am trying to create a Vertex Shader object via ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader().. the parameters ask for a pointer to the shader bytecode, and the length of the bytecode. Thus, I have the following struct:

```
struct shaderData
{
    char *shaderCode;
    UINT size;
};
```

And the following function, which returns this struct in an attempt to get the shader byte code (i use visual studio 2012, and fxc.exe to compile my shaders into compiled shader object (.cso) files.

```
struct shaderData *CubeApp::GetShaderByteCode(char *compiledShader)
{
    FILE *pFile = 0;
    char *shaderCode = 0;
    UINT fSize = 0;
    UINT numRead = 0;
    struct shaderData *sData = (struct shaderData *)malloc(sizeof(struct shaderData));

    pFile = fopen(compiledShader, "rb");

    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    fSize = ftell(pFile);
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    shaderCode = (char *)malloc(fSize);

    while (numRead != fSize)
        numRead = fread(&shaderCode[numRead], 1, fSize, pFile);

    fclose(pFile);

    sData->shaderCode = shaderCode;
    sData->size = fSize;

    return sData;
}
```

I call the function like so:

```
struct shaderData *sData = GetShaderByteCode("VShader.cso");
```

But, when I call ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader(), passing sData->shaderCode, and sData->size as parameters, my vertex shader object (ID3D11VertexShader) returns as NULL, and the function returns E_INVALIDARG.

Maybe I have a wrong understanding of what the shader bytecode is, but shouldn't this function be giving me the correct parameter to pass into CreateVertexShader?

Comment: I seem to remember getting this when I compiled the shader with an unsupported shader model version. I can't remember if it was too low or too high, but CreateVertexShader refused to load the binary shader .  This probably isn't your problem but I thought I'd mentioned it as you might not think to look for that just in case.

Comment: The other thing to ask is have you tried creating the device with debug enabled and looking at the debug output, it's often very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct shaderData
{
    BYTE *shaderCode;
    UINT size;
};
```

The shader byte code needs to be unsigned char (which is what the BYTE type is). I am not sure if it is the only problem with your code, but on my side it works fine with this type.